# Create a center line for each polygon

Tags: qgis, python

I am trying to create a line in the center of each polygon of my shape like the red lines in the picture below (all polygons are rectangles).
There's almost 22.000 polygons and I can't figure out how to do this.
Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: please provide more information about your geometries ... are they always rectangles ?

Comment: Yes @snaileater always rectangles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all polygons are rectangles, i guess you are looking for the average of the long sides.

In this case, if it is a one time task, this should do the trick:

1. start at point 0 of the border and check if distance from 0 to 1 is lower than distance from 0 to 3.
2. case true: get coordinates of midpoint of sides 0-1 and 2-3.
3. case false: get cooridnates of midpoint of sides 2-3 and 0-3.
4. Build new line geometry using the just fount midpoints

In QGIS:

Use the field calculator to get the coordinates:

build 4 columns:

X1:

```
if(($x_at(0)-$x_at(1))^2+($y_at(0)-$y_at(1))^2 < ($x_at(0)-$x_at(3))^2+($y_at(0)-$y_at(3))^2,$x_at(0)/2+$x_at(1)/2,$x_at(0)/2+$x_at(3)/2)
```

Y1:

```
if(($x_at(0)-$x_at(1))^2+($y_at(0)-$y_at(1))^2 < ($x_at(0)-$x_at(3))^2+($y_at(0)-$y_at(3))^2,$y_at(0)/2+$y_at(1)/2,$y_at(0)/2+$y_at(3)/2)
```

X2:

```
if(($x_at(0)-$x_at(1))^2+($y_at(0)-$y_at(1))^2 < ($x_at(0)-$x_at(3))^2+($y_at(0)-$y_at(3))^2,$x_at(2)/2+$x_at(3)/2,$x_at(1)/2+$x_at(2)/2)
```

Y2:

```
if(($x_at(0)-$x_at(1))^2+($y_at(0)-$y_at(1))^2 < ($x_at(0)-$x_at(3))^2+($y_at(0)-$y_at(3))^2,$y_at(2)/2+$y_at(3)/2,$y_at(1)/2+$y_at(2)/2)
```

Then build the geometry column

wkt_geometry:

```
concat('LINESTRING( ',"X1",' ',"Y1",',',"X2",' ',"Y2",')')
```

Then, export layer as csv, and reload it with the csv driver, set wkt_geometry as the geometry field.

Comment: Please edit the question adding the new info.

Comment: it's worked, but partially...some lines had a weird behavior, didn't get parallels. But now I understand. On some rectangles there are vertex dividing the longer side of polygon.

Comment: Ok, if this fits your needs, please edit the question to add that info, i.e: all polygons are rectangles. And accept the answer. Did you try simplify geometries in order to drop the extra mid-side vertexes?

Comment: I used simplify now and it worked very well...thank you very much.